# Can't open close vote pop-up (again)

Tags: bug

It's really hard to clean up the site when the close vote pop-up doesn't pop up.
[image]

This isn't the first time sand I tried repeatedly, even flushing the browser cache and the proxy cache between tries.

Comment: Considering the frequency with which you receive these errors, and the infrequency anyone else see them, I'm awfully tempted to attribute them to your system (browser, computer, network, proxy, something). What browser are you running, also what proxy?

Comment: The latest version of Chrome on the latest version of OS X, with Squid on a Smoothwall box. Neither of which are unusual and I believe Chrome is one of the browsers SE officially supports. When these issues occur I have no problems with any other site. There is absolutely nothing to indicate the problem is at my end. The fact that I get the error message indicates that the problem occurred at the server end, otherwise I wouldn't even get that to pop up.

Comment: I absolutely agree that your computer indicates the problem is on SE's end; but the heuristic implication is the opposite. Does the problem resolve itself? If so, so you have any notion of how long it takes between you first noticing and resolution?

Comment: The problem does indeed resolve itself but as I received this particular error just before going to bed it's not possible for me to know how long it took, other than to say it's working now, about 12 hours later. I think this is an issue the devs will need to consult the logs about.

Comment: If you happen to notice it sometime, try to see if it resolves itself after <30 minutes. We've noticed a lot of "wonkiness" with the caching tier and I believe it's timeout is ~30 minutes.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what happens next time.

Comment: You **really** should have an IT professional take a look at your computer.  It seems to be misbehaving a lot. =D

Comment: @HopelessN00b, I would of course but I just don't know where to find one.

Comment: This appears to be a timeout on your side not even reaching us...our traffic logs show no errors in the time period this question was posted (or any close dialog load).  Are you going through a proxy, or have any other trouble reaching US sites in general?

Comment: @Nick, there is no delay in the error being displayed, which indicates there is no timeout involved. At the time in question I have no problems with other sites or SF in general and response times all round were good. There is a proxy involved but its cache was flushed, as was the browser cache, before re-attempting to cast a vote.